# How to get tapped List Item position in Adapter class on button click

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

I am trying to get tapped list item position in Adapter class on button click, but did not get any success

First of all i have to get tapped list item and then want to delete that row

getting something like this: `D/strPosition::-(1922): com.and.field.Transport@b3ddf5c0`

using below code:

```
viewHolder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {         

                strPosition = arrayList.get(position).toString();
                Log.d("strPosition::-", strPosition);

                // and then want to delete that row using tapped position

                strName = arrayList.get(position).getName().toString();                         

            }
        });
```

Comment: don't you already have the position? In your variable named position? I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use `position` in your `onClick` method, instead use next approach

```
viewHolder.btnDelete.setTag(position);
viewHolder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            Integer taggedPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
            Log.d("Position::-", Integer.toString(taggedPosition));
            strName = arrayList.get(taggedPosition).getName().toString();
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Sun you used `ArrayAdapter`, so you don't need to store `arrayList` there, because you already passed it into super constructor. Use adapter's methods to [get](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem(int)), [remove](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#remove(T)), etc. instead.

Comment: Why not using OnItemClickListener ? onItemClick will give the position on the clicked item, no need to set the tag or anything like that...

Comment: @2Dee because author has button there, which does another action (delete) vs item click (view, for example)

Comment: @gio please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107440/how-to-refresh-listview-after-deletion-of-list-row