# How to Refresh ListView after deletion of list row

Tags: android

I have written a code to delete a row in a list view but that row is still visible in a list, I am using `notifyDataSetChanged()` and here is what i have used:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Transport> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Transport> arrayList;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    int resource;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;  
    View view;  

    Helper helper;
    List<NameValuePair> params;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    String strName = null, strAlwaysZero = null, strPosition = null;
    Integer taggedPosition;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Transport> arrayList) {
        super(context, resource, arrayList);
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, null);
            viewHolder.textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            viewHolder.btnDelete = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.textName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.btnDelete.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {         
                taggedPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
                Log.d("Position::-", Integer.toString(taggedPosition));

                new DeleteRecord().execute();
            }
        });

        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

class DeleteRecord extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {      

     /**
    * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
    * */

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();

   }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        strUrlUpdate = "http://somerurl.tld/result.php";
        helper = new Helper();

        params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();        
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sName", strName));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sKey", strAlwaysZero));        

        strServerResult  = helper.getHttpPost(strUrlUpdate ,params);

        strStatusId = "0";
        strMessage = "Unknow Status!";

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(strServerResult);
            strStatusId = jsonObject.getString("StatusID");

             if (!strStatusId.equals("0")) {
                 Log.d("background-Position::-", Integer.toString(taggedPosition));
                arrayList.remove(taggedPosition);
             }
            strMessage = jsonObject.getString("Message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                                     

       return null;

    }
    /**
    * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
    * **/
   protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        // Prepare Save Data
        if (strStatusId.equals("0")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to remove record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Record removed successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                     
        }

   }

}
```

Comment: Put your Network call in `AsyncTask` and called    `notifyDataSetChanged();` in `onPostExecute(.....)`

Comment: @MD i followed the way you taught me but still not done

Comment: @Sun do you use filtering at your adapter?

Answer (score 0):

put `arrayList.remove(taggedPosition)` in `doinBackground()` method.

```
class DeleteRecord extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {      

     /**
    * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
    * */

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();

   }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        strUrlUpdate = "http://somerurl.tld/result.php";
        helper = new Helper();

        params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();        
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sName", strName));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sKey", strAlwaysZero));        

        strServerResult  = helper.getHttpPost(strUrlUpdate ,params);

        strStatusId = "0";
        strMessage = "Unknow Status!";

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(strServerResult);
            strStatusId = jsonObject.getString("StatusID");

             if (!strStatusId.equals("0")) {
                arrayList.remove(taggedPosition);
             }
            strMessage = jsonObject.getString("Message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                                         

       return null;

    }
    /**
    * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
    * **/
   protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        // Prepare Save Data
        if (strStatusId.equals("0")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to remove record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Record removed successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                     
        }

   }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

use the adapter name for example adaptername.notifyDataSetChanged();